# PointerProperty with ShapeKey

Tags: python, shape-keys, data-blocks

In the docs it's stated that PointerProperties must be `derived from ID or ID Property Group`. ShapeKeys are not derived from these and so cannot have PoitnerProperties made from them.

However, in the bpy docs, `relative_key` is stated as being of `Type: ShapeKey` and in the UI it has a search box and performs like a PointerProperty, updating itself if the name of the targeted shape key is changed. So unless this is an exception hard coded into Blender, there must be a way of doing it.

Does anyone know how I can find exactly how the relative_key variable has been set up, or a way of replicating this funcitonality?

Comment: Hello ! FWIW here's where this comes from. https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_data_mesh.py#L416 You can inspect UI elements with Rgiht Click > Edit Source if you have developper tools enabled and it will add a new text block with the relevant script.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware, but this just shows where the `prop_search` is made, it doesn't show 'how' the relative_key itself is set up (as in its PropertyGroup creation).